# How to find matches between csv files based on two columns within a range

Tags: python, loops, csv, match, matching

I'm currently struggling to put together some code that will find the matches of values in two different columns in two `csv` files within a range.  I have tried using the code below, but it doesn't output what I am trying to accomplish.  Basically, I want to output a new file that contains all of the lines in the second file that have matches to the same columns in the first file, not merge them together.  I've added more detailed clarification below my code.  I feel like what I've done so far is probably completely wrong.  What do I need to change in order for my code to produce the results I am looking for?

```
import csv

with open('F435W.csv') as csvF435:
    readCSV1 = csv.reader(csvF435, delimiter=',')
    with open("F550Mnew.csv", "w") as new_F550M:
        pass
    with open("F550Mnew.csv", "a") as new_F550M:
        for header in readCSV1:
            new_F550M.write(','.join(header)+'\n')
            break
        for l435 in readCSV1:
            with open('F550M.csv') as csvF550:
                readCSV2 = csv.reader(csvF550, delimiter=',')
                for l550 in readCSV2:
                    if isfloat(l435[12]) and isfloat(l550[12]) and abs(float(l435[12])-float(l550[12])) < 0.002778:
                        if isfloat(l435[13]) and isfloat(l550[13]) and abs(float(l435[13])-float(l550[13])) < 0.002778:
                            new_F550M.write(','.join(l550)+'\n')
```

For clarification, each file has an `X` column and a `Y` column so basically each row corresponds to an `(X,Y)` point. In addition, there are 21 other columns of data that are not necessary for finding matches, but need to be included in the final output file. I am trying to find points in the second file that match the points in the first file within a radius.  This is because I know that none of my points will be exact matches.  In my data, my `X` is column 13 and my `Y` is column 14.

The way I have tried to accomplish this is by finding the differences between every `X` in the first file and every `X` in the second file (eg. `X1-X2`), and the differences between every `Y` in the first file and every `Y` in the second file (eg. `Y1-Y2`).  Then, every row in the second file which corresponds to differences for both `X` and `Y` which are less than my radius value (0.0002778) would be considered a match to the first file.

Unfortunately, my code produces a file with over 300,000 points when my original files only have 7000 points.  There should be less data, not more data.  It also includes many repeats of data, when there should not be any repeats at all.
Thank you for your time!

Sample of what the data looks like:  I apologize for the length, but I am afraid they will not contain enough matches to be useful if I don't include enough of the data.

F435W.csv (file 1)

```
1,2017.013,0.01242859,-8.2618,0,51434.12,0.3269918,-11.7781,0,0.01957931,1387.9406,541.916,49.9898514,41.5266996,8.81E+01,1.63E+03,1.44E+02,40.535,8.65,84.72,0.00061,0.00035,62.14
2,84.73392,0.01245409,-4.8201,0.0002,112.9723,0.04012135,-5.1324,0.0004,-0.002142646,150.306,146.7986,49.9942613,41.5444392,4.92E+00,5.60E+00,-2.02E-01,2.379,2.206,-74.69,0.00339,0.0029,88.88
3,215.1939,0.01242859,-5.8321,0.0001,262.2751,0.03840466,-6.0469,0.0002,-0.002961465,3248.686,52.8478,50.003155,41.5019044,4.77E+00,5.05E+00,-1.63E-01,2.263,2.166,-65.29,0.002,0.0019,-66.78
4,0.3796681,0.01240305,1.0515,0.0355,0.5823653,0.05487975,0.587,0.1023,-0.00425157,3760.344,11.113,50.0051049,41.4949256,1.93E+00,1.02E+00,-7.42E-02,1.393,1.007,-4.61,0.05461,0.03818,-6.68
5,0.9584663,0.01249223,0.0461,0.0142,1.043696,0.0175857,-0.0464,0.0183,-0.004156116,4013.2063,9.1225,50.0057256,41.4914444,1.12E+00,9.75E-01,1.09E-01,1.085,0.957,28.34,0.01934,0.01745,44.01
6,2.379565,0.01249223,-0.9412,0.0057,0.231205,0.02710035,1.59,0.1273,-0.004135321,3824.3706,9.0756,50.0052903,41.4940468,7.81E-01,6.99E-02,4.27E-02,0.885,0.26,3.42,0.01265,0.00622,15.52
7,0.3171223,0.01250492,1.2469,0.0428,0.5233852,0.05406558,0.7029,0.1122,-0.00399635,4097.3604,7.0301,50.0059585,41.4902884,9.61E-01,1.63E+00,-3.94E-01,1.346,0.883,-65.16,0.06171,0.04005,-65.05
8,0.289245,0.0125176,1.3468,0.047,0.2744479,0.02238134,1.4039,0.0886,-0.004173243,3904.7402,7.3912,50.0055069,41.4929422,7.90E-01,2.38E-01,7.13E-02,0.894,0.479,7.24,0.04501,0.02071,8.29
9,0.3543034,0.01247953,1.1266,0.0383,0.7666836,0.06376094,0.2885,0.0903,-0.004009248,4107.0684,3.259,50.0060503,41.4901611,3.53E+00,1.28E+00,-4.60E-01,1.903,1.09,-11.12,0.06873,0.03955,-11.22
10,1.308331,0.01250492,-0.2918,0.0104,-0.005209296,0.004877397,99,99,-0.004193406,3933.9834,6,50.0056001,41.4925416,5.78E-01,8.33E-02,0.00E+00,0.76,0.289,0,0.01272,0.00424,0
11,3.995717,0.01250492,-1.504,0.0034,0.1589517,0.007450347,1.9968,0.0509,-0.003990021,4069.0469,3.0234,50.0059668,41.4906855,8.03E-01,2.29E-02,1.02E-02,0.896,0.151,0.75,0.00888,0.00361,5.59
12,1.067634,0.01250492,-0.0711,0.0127,0.1260926,0.02787585,2.2483,0.2401,-0.004042602,4048.9148,4,50.0059023,41.4909612,7.40E-01,8.33E-02,0.00E+00,0.86,0.289,0,0.02449,0.00576,0
13,0.2808423,0.01162418,1.3788,0.0449,0.4633991,0.02235104,0.8351,0.0524,-0.004015559,4114.6655,2.0641,50.0060898,41.4900585,9.65E-01,5.88E-01,-9.47E-02,0.994,0.752,-13.34,0.05405,0.03814,-15.13
14,1.067291,0.01245409,-0.0707,0.0127,1.081617,0.01516444,-0.0852,0.0152,-0.004168633,3960.8787,18.0524,50.0054405,41.4921501,6.84E-01,8.29E-01,-6.18E-02,0.923,0.813,-69.77,0.01468,0.01229,-78.83
15,0.5216251,0.0125176,0.7066,0.0261,0.584776,0.01824955,0.5825,0.0339,-0.003026338,2661.6533,58.4563,50.0016952,41.5099844,8.51E-01,1.17E+00,-7.27E-02,1.089,0.914,-77.72,0.03244,0.02498,-81.68
16,0.6062042,0.01249223,0.5435,0.0224,0.8726375,0.05509822,0.1479,0.0686,-0.003950399,4149.8169,31.0127,50.0056384,41.489524,9.30E-01,3.48E+00,2.03E-01,1.87,0.956,85.48,0.05307,0.0241,86.01
17,0.1324067,0.01242859,2.1952,0.1019,0.1208224,0.01290438,2.2946,0.116,-0.004166729,3911.6807,12.661,50.005426,41.4928374,2.17E-01,2.24E-01,-1.08E-01,0.574,0.335,-45.89,0.0721,0.04162,-44.98
18,0.2136006,0.01247953,1.676,0.0634,0.3511444,0.02471001,1.1363,0.0764,-0.003978713,4096.9111,15.6285,50.0057993,41.4902797,1.00E+00,4.37E-01,2.85E-01,1.058,0.564,22.64,0.07548,0.03957,23.17
19,0.1470979,0.01244135,2.081,0.0919,0.1216703,0.0168958,2.287,0.1508,-0.004147241,3695.311,13.7044,50.004907,41.4958173,2.14E-01,2.08E-01,9.20E-02,0.551,0.345,44.05,0.07073,0.04115,45.12
20,0.5434682,0.01250492,0.6621,0.025,0.5819249,0.01592951,0.5878,0.0297,-0.004136056,3866.6416,24.8316,50.0050981,41.493437,8.34E-01,9.96E-01,2.74E-01,1.096,0.793,53.22,0.02966,0.02055,58.08
21,0.2259093,0.01249223,1.6152,0.0601,0.2848583,0.01867901,1.3634,0.0712,-0.00409535,3645.521,20.0162,50.0046759,41.4964926,5.71E-01,4.26E-01,-1.11E-02,0.756,0.652,-4.34,0.03735,0.0305,0.08
22,0.9499883,0.01247953,0.0557,0.0143,0.9711754,0.01891141,0.0318,0.0211,-0.003134006,3378.7927,19.5305,50.0040686,41.5001691,8.66E-01,4.09E-01,3.57E-03,0.931,0.639,0.45,0.01623,0.01142,-1.19
23,1.125635,0.01240305,-0.1285,0.012,1.050538,0.02402694,-0.0535,0.0248,-0.003295973,3132.9458,24.9024,50.0034018,41.5035477,9.65E-01,7.83E-01,-1.44E-01,1.022,0.839,-28.88,0.01702,0.01288,-21
24,0.168302,0.01249223,1.9348,0.0806,0.2447732,0.01930529,1.5281,0.0857,-0.004140488,3904.7268,27.0386,50.0051454,41.4929084,4.47E-01,4.56E-01,-1.28E-02,0.682,0.662,-54.61,0.04399,0.04068,89.66
25,0.0542859,0.01244135,3.1633,0.2489,0.08799078,0.007964755,2.6389,0.0983,-0.003241792,3454.2612,25.2749,50.0041373,41.4991191,1.93E-01,1.99E-01,-7.18E-02,0.518,0.353,-46.27,0.06408,0.03839,-44.76
26,0.4379335,0.01242859,0.8965,0.0308,0.4661828,0.01542368,0.8286,0.0359,-0.00336337,3478.7058,32.3355,50.0040639,41.4987701,6.15E-01,8.96E-01,-2.91E-02,0.948,0.782,-84.15,0.02891,0.02521,-70.04
27,0.1515608,0.01249223,2.0485,0.0895,0.1935181,0.01712885,1.7832,0.0961,-0.002904789,2982.0017,29.9904,50.0029594,41.505619,3.46E-01,3.61E-01,1.55E-05,0.601,0.588,89.94,0.05241,0.05241,-80.48
28,0.6658883,0.01250492,0.4415,0.0204,0.718064,0.01780974,0.3596,0.0269,-0.00324104,3408.0103,36.2539,50.0038284,41.4997375,9.45E-01,1.11E+00,1.98E-01,1.115,0.902,56.45,0.02706,0.02147,51.52
29,0.7244126,0.01244135,0.35,0.0187,1.030102,0.02744665,-0.0322,0.0289,-0.00280412,3259.0889,37.3165,50.0034648,41.5017879,8.65E-01,1.01E+00,5.85E-02,1.017,0.919,70.87,0.02225,0.02011,55.79
30,0.1651701,0.01247953,1.9552,0.0821,0.163293,0.01641976,1.9676,0.1092,-0.003909466,3595.4846,31.9761,50.0043403,41.4971614,2.50E-01,4.42E-01,2.21E-01,0.766,0.324,56.75,0.08087,0.03087,58.28
```

F550M.csv (file 2)

```
2,1921.566,0.01258874,-8.2091,0,37128.06,0.2618096,-11.4243,0,0.01455503,4617.5225,554.576,49.9887896,41.5264699,6.09E+01,8.09E+02,1.78E+01,28.459,7.779,88.63,0.00054,0.00036,77.04
3,1.055918,0.01256313,-0.0591,0.0129,9.834856,0.1109255,-2.4819,0.0122,-0.002955142,3936.4946,85.3255,49.9949149,41.5370016,3.98E+01,1.23E+01,1.54E+01,6.83,2.336,24.13,0.06362,0.01965,23.98
4,151.2355,0.01260153,-5.4491,0.0001,184.0693,0.03634057,-5.6625,0.0002,-0.002626019,3409.2642,76.9891,49.9931935,41.5442109,4.02E+00,4.35E+00,-1.47E-03,2.086,2.005,-89.75,0.00227,0.00198,66.61
5,0.3506025,0.01258874,1.138,0.039,0.3466277,0.01300407,1.1503,0.0407,-0.002441164,3351.9893,8.9147,49.9942299,41.5451727,4.97E-01,5.07E-01,7.21E-03,0.715,0.702,62.75,0.02,0.01989,82.88
6,1.166133,0.01257594,-0.1669,0.0117,0.005819145,0.009692424,5.5879,1.8089,-0.003201006,3476.9932,10,49.9946543,41.5434658,5.88E-01,8.33E-02,0.00E+00,0.767,0.289,0,0.01497,0.00499,0
7,0.1372164,0.0125503,2.1565,0.0993,0.1238123,0.02608246,2.2681,0.2288,-0.003556473,3535.5281,13.4586,49.9947993,41.5426587,2.49E-01,2.48E-01,-7.69E-03,0.506,0.491,-43.27,0.05264,0.05237,-55.87
8,0.6174777,0.01260153,0.5234,0.0222,0.6206718,0.01300407,0.5178,0.0228,-0.002441164,3357.0044,20.0487,49.9940449,41.5450748,5.10E-01,5.22E-01,-6.28E-03,0.724,0.712,-66.7,0.01194,0.01192,84.82
9,1.46848,0.01260153,-0.4172,0.0093,0.001897994,0.009688255,6.8043,5.5435,-0.003612399,3584.0171,16,49.9949252,41.5419909,5.87E-01,8.33E-02,0.00E+00,0.766,0.289,0,0.01175,0.00392,0
10,1.452348,0.01258874,-0.4052,0.0094,3.124427,0.04807406,-1.2369,0.0167,-0.003148756,3805.6069,39.5791,49.9952831,41.5389075,2.25E+00,3.87E+00,-6.77E-01,2.03,1.416,-70.08,0.0302,0.01891,-67.61
11,0.1548658,0.01260153,2.0251,0.0884,0.1777253,0.01630147,1.8756,0.0996,-0.002919044,3459.7681,25.6248,49.9943085,41.5436591,4.64E-01,2.34E-01,8.40E-02,0.701,0.455,18.09,0.05739,0.03321,18.33
12,0.5046132,0.01253746,0.7426,0.027,0.7798272,0.04462456,0.27,0.0621,-0.00261193,3418.9119,65.5326,49.9934365,41.5441099,6.87E-01,2.77E+00,-2.92E-01,1.678,0.804,-82.19,0.05363,0.02182,-83.28
13,0.380733,0.01260153,1.0484,0.0359,0.4313257,0.01605258,0.913,0.0404,-0.003497544,3548.8484,34.5602,49.9944623,41.542421,8.27E-01,8.51E-01,8.92E-02,0.964,0.865,48.75,0.03776,0.03252,30.61
14,0.1643925,0.01258874,1.9603,0.0832,0.2181225,0.01839054,1.6532,0.0916,-0.003121084,3710.6785,33.3215,49.9950598,41.5402182,2.18E-01,2.18E-01,1.03E-01,0.567,0.339,45,0.0757,0.04376,45
15,0.3959635,0.01260153,1.0059,0.0346,0.9984215,0.0763398,0.0017,0.083,-0.003106286,3805.9988,48.3363,49.995125,41.5388789,1.87E+00,3.12E+00,4.86E-01,1.813,1.304,71.09,0.0559,0.04105,67.61
16,0.1625628,0.01260153,1.9724,0.0842,0.3490304,0.02234424,1.1428,0.0695,-0.002472953,3410.77,38.0388,49.9939083,41.544294,1.77E-01,4.75E-01,8.92E-03,0.689,0.421,88.29,0.0769,0.04707,89.86
17,0.1725209,0.01260153,1.9079,0.0793,0.2965718,0.02357189,1.3197,0.0863,-0.003454017,3629.0247,40.9706,49.9946304,41.541311,3.73E-01,7.91E-01,-3.73E-01,1.004,0.393,-59.65,0.09781,0.03734,-58.27
18,0.3034717,0.01260153,1.2947,0.0451,0.5031242,0.02774418,0.7458,0.0599,-0.003073985,4079.0825,42,49.9962105,41.5351731,6.68E-01,8.33E-02,0.00E+00,0.818,0.289,0,0.06348,0.02106,0
19,1.593927,0.01260153,-0.5062,0.0086,1.860803,0.0219809,-0.6743,0.0128,-0.003038161,4065.9434,58.3703,49.9958657,41.5353087,1.75E+00,1.41E+00,-7.15E-03,1.323,1.188,-1.21,0.01697,0.01464,-0.43
20,0.5464995,0.01258874,0.656,0.025,0.5661472,0.0144696,0.6177,0.0278,-0.003053429,4045.0474,54.439,49.9958631,41.535604,5.43E-01,8.46E-01,-1.22E-03,0.92,0.737,-89.77,0.02257,0.01649,-89.72
21,1.303251,0.01253746,-0.2876,0.0104,1.296672,0.01418861,-0.2821,0.0119,-0.00259741,4240.1406,55.2714,49.9965409,41.5329423,6.05E-01,6.81E-01,7.89E-03,0.826,0.777,84.15,0.00892,0.00852,69.62
22,0.5174786,0.01260153,0.7153,0.0264,0.5260691,0.01390194,0.6974,0.0287,-0.003019847,3828.95,55.19,49.9950817,41.5385478,5.18E-01,7.56E-01,-6.34E-02,0.879,0.709,-75.96,0.0236,0.01643,-75.02
23,0.1551826,0.01260153,2.0229,0.0882,0.166565,0.01726119,1.946,0.1125,-0.003271136,3504.7439,52.7386,49.9939745,41.5429739,1.91E-01,6.86E-01,1.89E-01,0.866,0.356,71.33,0.10376,0.04235,71.56
24,0.2214222,0.01260153,1.6369,0.0618,0.2389908,0.01360924,1.554,0.0618,-0.00285033,3750.3167,54.0027,49.994824,41.5396229,4.32E-01,5.51E-01,1.68E-03,0.742,0.657,89.18,0.04862,0.04505,89.94
25,0.1336059,0.01253746,2.1854,0.1019,0.1320868,0.009830156,2.1979,0.0808,-0.002921393,3459.6851,51.7091,49.9938331,41.5435908,2.16E-01,2.06E-01,-9.16E-02,0.55,0.345,-43.52,0.06231,0.03626,-45.19
26,0.1703959,0.01260153,1.9214,0.0803,0.1577456,0.0152816,2.0051,0.1052,-0.002779523,3446.95,49,49.9938372,41.5437717,7.29E-01,8.33E-02,0.00E+00,0.854,0.289,0,0.11183,0.03721,0
27,1.896325,0.01258874,-0.6948,0.0072,1.941203,0.0152816,-0.7202,0.0085,-0.00306097,3809.6836,57.8143,49.9949655,41.5388035,7.38E-01,6.80E-01,7.46E-03,0.86,0.824,7.18,0.00713,0.00678,59.71
28,0.6522877,0.01260153,0.4639,0.021,0.1713469,0.01312423,1.9153,0.0832,-0.002447558,4271.9614,52,49.9967135,41.5325172,5.92E-01,8.33E-02,0.00E+00,0.77,0.289,0,0.0274,0.00913,0
29,0.1370073,0.0125503,2.1581,0.0995,0.101415,0.02614047,2.4847,0.2799,-0.002207851,4324.667,55.3374,49.99684,41.5317898,2.22E-01,2.24E-01,1.12E-01,0.579,0.332,45.18,0.07753,0.04476,45
30,0.2240251,0.01253746,1.6243,0.0608,0.2254432,0.01360924,1.6174,0.0656,-0.003037372,3960.3042,58.9024,49.9954807,41.5367473,4.18E-01,4.81E-01,-1.07E-02,0.695,0.645,-80.65,0.03802,0.03492,-88.86
```

Comment: You have a lot of loops in your code. Write a function which reads data from csv file to a list, open all your needed csv files into lists with this function, process the data, put the final data into a list, and then write it into the new csv file.

Comment: Thank you.  I'll try that again.  I think that was probably my initial approach but I was never able to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

You are complicating the program by nesting all the loops and conditionals. Break it down into simple steps.

Do the following.
1. Read both the csv files and convert them into 2d lists.
2. Compare the columns/values of the lists within a loop based on the given index, add the rows from second list to a new output list.
3. Write the output list to a csv file.

```
def read_file(filepath):
    with open(filepath,'r') as f:
        x = csv.reader(f)
        l = list(x)  
    return l  

l435 = read_file('F435W.csv')
l550 = read_file('F550M.csv')
new_F550M = []
r = 0.002778

for i in l550:
    for j in l435:
       # I did't exactly get your if condition, so I am putting it down based on what I understood, so if it is wrong, modify it accordingly.
       if isfloat(i[12]) and isfloat(j[12]) and abs(float(i[12]) float(j[12])) < r:
            if isfloat(i[13]) and isfloat(j[13]) and abs(float(i[13]) float(j[13])) < r:
                new_F550M.append(i)

with open('new_F550M.csv','w') as f:
    out = csv.writer(f)
    out.writerows(new_F550M)
```

Comment: I understand.  Thank you.  There must be something wrong with my if statements then.  I'm trying to use them to find the rows where both the column 13 value and column 14 value in F435W.csv are within 0.0002778 of the column 13 and column 14 values in F550M.csv, but this is probably not the right approach.  I'm not even sure if the if statements are what I should use for this or not.  I seem to be getting rows that match but some are repeated in the output file several times, and some are not repeated, only appearing once.